# How to do Inner JOIN on two _index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I going to do a query that related to two _index ( `conn`, `http`). In sql it can be do like following, may I know how DSL query like in elasticSearch ? Please assist me, I really out of idea.

```
SELECT *  FROM elastic INNER JOIN conn ON conn.uid=http.uid 
WHERE elastic.date BETWEEN '2016-08-20  00:00:00' and '2016-08-22 13:41:09'
AND conn.service='http' ;
```

Comment: Elasticsearch is nosql (non-relational) so the concept of joining does not exist.  Also, joining involves table scans in SQL, which has the potential to murder performance for ES if you try to implement something like that.  If you want to get a date range from an index, you can use a range query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: Hi @ryanlutgen, i wanted to use relational is because i need to get some information at another _index whereby both of the _index1 and _index2 only related with each others with same uid. Any idea how to do this kind of sorting ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch doesn't have support for joins like SQL.

They discuss the handling of relationships in the definitive guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html